# Searching text file with prefix

Tags: c++, search, text-files

I have a text file with a name/place on each line. Is there a simple way of searching the text file based on a prefix entered by user and printing every line that starts with that prefix.

Comment: Define _simple_ please!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should iterate through each line of the file and check its contents. This can be done via ifstream like this:

```
ifstream file("text.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        // match
    }
}
```

The actual approach for matching the item depends on the complexity of the prefix.

For simple cases you could just use the string [compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) method. For example:

```
if (!line.compare(0, matchSize, matchPrefix))
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Or [string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and check the result for `0`.

If the match conditions are more complex you could try using [regular expressions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/). However, it depends on the actual format of the prefix expected from user.

You should also consider whether case sensitivity is an issue and either preprocess the compared strings with [std::transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) and `toupper/tolower` or write your own predicate to use with [std::equal](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal/). For example:

```
string prefix = "ab";
bool match = std::equal(prefix.begin(), prefix.end(), line.begin(), [](const char& c1, const char& c2)
{
    return tolower(c1) == tolower(c2);
});
```

As you can see there are many solutions for such a problem (and many more). Which one should be adopted depends on specific requirements and the handled cases for user input.

Comment: _"For example:"_ Dead end road?

Comment: Due to missing information on what the user might actually enter I considered to remove that part until more details are known.